# Boost::asio what is this kind of strange coding style?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am about to debug something within my boost asio socket communication. And found this piece of code inside of the asio library (found in boost/asio/impl/write.hpp line 169 (boost 1.47) ):

```
  switch (start)
  {
    case 1:
    buffers_.prepare(this->check_for_completion(ec, total_transferred_));
    for (;;)
    {
      stream_.async_write_some(buffers_,
          BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(write_op)(*this));
      return; 
    default:
      total_transferred_ += bytes_transferred;
      buffers_.consume(bytes_transferred);
      buffers_.prepare(this->check_for_completion(ec, total_transferred_));
      if ((!ec && bytes_transferred == 0)
          || buffers_.begin() == buffers_.end())
        break;
    }

    handler_(ec, static_cast<const std::size_t&>(total_transferred_));
  }
```

I have already a lot of  years of C/C++ development experience, but never ever in my life I saw such kind of weird implementation. Look there, the default: label of the switch statement is within the for loop.

If I understand this right, then the switch statement is "misused" instead of a goto, right (for the cases where start != 1, goto default:)? 
Is it actually a valid C/C++ with respect to the standard?
What will happen if I for example put

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
```

instead of the for loop in the original code. Will "i" be undefined in case when jump is performed to default: label? Sure I might use a debugger here, however this seems so suspicious for me, that I think this could produce different behavior for different compilers.

Comment: Seems like the `for` loop itself is used as a `goto`. If the `break` is not executed, the next iteration will surely terminate before the `default` label due to the `return`. Pretty hairy stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is well-defined, valid code. A `switch` really is a glorified `goto`. For some clever use of this construct, take a look at [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).

As for your `for`, that wouldn't be legal. A jump to a case label can't cross an initialization.

Comment: Are you sure that this is really well defined? I mean Duff misused switch instead of goto. He even argued  that he don't know if this is good or bad to be able to use switches like this.

Comment: I think you could make a coherent argument that it's not well-defined, but I think the stronger argument is that it's well-defined. It's well-defined for `goto`, and they both jump to the same type of destination. (Cases and default are statement labels, just like the targets of `goto`.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a version of [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).